# BrokenProcessPool while running code in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am learning about multiprocessing in python. I have the following code snippet:

```py
import time
import concurrent.futures

def wait(seconds):
    print(f'Waiting {seconds} seconds...')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return f'Done'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        p = executor.submit(wait,1)
        print(p.result())
```

Running it gives me this error:

```py
BrokenProcessPool                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-8eff57e3a077> in <module>
      9     with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
     10         p = executor.submit(do_something,1)
---> 11         print(p.result())

~\.conda\envs\w\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    433                 raise CancelledError()
    434             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 435                 return self.__get_result()
    436             else:
    437                 raise TimeoutError()

~\.conda\envs\w\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

I am on a Windows computer and I have used `if __name__ == "__main__":` in my code. But I still get this error.

Comment: I referred all these SO posts but didn't find a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923476/concurrent-futures-code-ends-up-with-brokenprocesspool

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581158/multiprocessing-help-brokenprocesspool-error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611414/jupyter-notebook-always-gives-brokenprocesspool-error-while-executing-qiskit-cod

Comment: did you try restarting the nb and running the code again?

Comment: @YOLO yes I did it but still I am getting this error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it to work! I saved the `wait` function in a separate python file called `wait.py` and imported it in jupyter notebook.

`wait.py`:

```py
import time

def wait(seconds):
    print(f'Waiting {seconds} seconds...')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return f'Done'
```

`ipynb file`:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import wait #import the wait file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        p = executor.submit(wait.wait,1)
        print(p.result())
```

Comment: Got the idea for this from here : https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac